# Classic API pt-BR Forum Submission (UK Account)

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

Hopefully someone here can help with what I hope is a basic question.

I'm creating a basic form for a donation amount in Brazilian Real, however when the submit button is pressed it re-directs to a UK Paypal site in English (which means the people submitting a donation dont understand it).  The amount goes though correctly in BRL but is there any way to force the site to use a pt-BR language?

I've tried using https://www.paypal.com.br/cgi-bin/webscr and https://www.paypal.com/br/cgi-bin/webscr in the action but neither work.

Anyone have any ideas please?  Paypal are saying I need to register a BR paypal account (which I cant do as I dont have a bank account over there)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" NAME="currency_code" value="BRL">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="pt-BR">
<input type="hidden" name="DoExpressCheckoutPayment" value="BR">
<input type="hidden" name="SetExpressCheckout" value="BR">
<input type="hidden" name="DoReferenceTransaction" value="BR">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@url.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Doar">
Digite Relaçao Em R$  <input type="visible" name="amount" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1200">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="return" value="http://URL.com/?page_id=310">
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="http://URL.com/images/buttons/donate.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay  online">
</form>
```

Comment: I cant answer my own question, but it turns out it was a typo on my part - <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="pt-BR"> It should have been (note the _ and not - in the ) <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="pt_BR">